# UK Citizen attending school in UK with American spouse, which visa does the spouse need?

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens, study

My UK citizen spouse has been living in the US with me for over 10 years (I’m American). He just got into a UK Graduate program. Our plan is to get the degree and then return to the USA afterwards. Which visa do I need?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The visa (not VISA, which understood as a credit card company) would probably depend on how you plan to support yourself during the 2x 6 months period. **Leave to enter** would probably be denied without this being clarified beforhand.

Comment: Have you researched via https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa? For clarity, how long is the graduate program?

Comment: This may be the type of visa that you may need: [Family visas: apply, extend or switch - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa) *You need a family visa to live with a family member in the UK for more than 6 months.*  **Apply outside the UK:** *Cost if joining your partner, parent or child £1,523.*

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't really a good option for this.  You might want to consider applying for a graduate program yourself.

Comment: @MarkJohnson plus the NHS surcharge.  It's probably less costly, if impractical, for the UK citizen spouse to renounce his British citizenship and for the couple to apply for a student visa and a dependant visa.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone! Hgrl81, how long did it take to receive your spouse visa from start to finish? Then did they give you a 30 day window to enter the UK? I’ve read it normally takes 12 weeks, but could take up to 24 and that you have to enter the UK during a window of 30 days or reapply?

Comment: @phoog if the UK citizenship is renounced then they are no longer eligible for "home fees" that are capped (to £9250/year for bachelors I believe).

Comment: @kiradotee I suppose that's likely to change the financial calculation considerably.

Answer (score 4):

As a US citizen who married a Brit and just went through this process this year, you will need a spouse visa, and it is EXPENSIVE now with the NHS surcharges having nearly tripled in the past year alone. The NHS charges were nearly the same as the cost of the visa, and there aren't any options to not pay them. If you get a spouse visa, and you will have to get that if you plan to stay in the UK more than 6 months, you will have to pay them. In total between the immigration lawyer, the visa cost and NHS fees it was over $7000.00.  And with how things have changed so drastically over the past year, you ABSOLUTELY need to get a lawyer! Our lawyer was amazing and his fees weren't bad.

Comment: I'd like to draw your attention to a [comment](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/22293/uk-citizen-attending-school-in-uk-with-american-spouse-which-visa-does-the-spou?noredirect=1#comment36982_22293) asking for your feedback.